# Django2.2 Context Manager | {{template_tags}} | Variable limit?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template view in Django2.2, where I added two models & queries to look up metrics on user data (how many articles they read each month).

I ran into a strange issue where if I place multiple context variables on the page, every variable on the page but the First Variable will return '0'. If I simply change the order of the variables in the markup, each date function appears to be calculating correctly (as long as it is the first to appear). I couldn't find anything about this in the docs...and I'm guessing that this isn't a great approach to display this information either and I should instead use a DjangoTemplateTag and perform the operations there.

*Define the Object & Query

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(userDashBoardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['readArticleList'] = Articles.objects.filter(Unread = False,userId = self.request.user.SFPK )
```

*To avoid making further queries, I mutated the query into a set to perform further functions

```
article_list = set(context['readArticleList'])
article_read_date = (article_list.read_date for article_list in article_list)
```

```
        context['articles_last30'] = len(set(x for x in article_read_date if x > timezone.now() - timedelta(days=30)))
        context['articles_last60'] = len(set(x for x in article_read_date if x > timezone.now() - timedelta(days=60)))
        context['articles_last90'] = len(set(x for x in article_read_date if x > timezone.now() - timedelta(days=90)))
        return context
```

```
{%  block content %}

{{articles_last30}}
{{articles_last60}}
{{articles_last90}}
{% endblock %}
<br/>
```

For context,context,context in the example above *using sample data

the output on the page is (4,0,0)

If the order is reversed, I get

(20,0,0)

NOTE: I am NOT receiving any errors in the console, and the page(s) are loading fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

-Thank you for your time =)

Comment: Your `article_read_date` is an iterator, so it is *exhausted* after the first `for` loop.

Comment: You are doing pre-mature optimization when you say, To avoid making further queries I converted it into a set. @Dssii3056. You can do what you are doing in a much simpler way.

Comment: Using a set might be a problem here, since it means that if there are multiple `Article`s with the same `read_date`, then it still counts as one.

Comment: Thanks again @WillemVanOnsem! ---@unlockme, I was under the impression that Django Queries create [lists], and that a set() is better served as long as I don't care about indexing the content of the collection....I'm probably wrong with regards to that as well, but just thought I would share the 'why'.

Comment: if it's a model.DateTimeField + wouldn't a user have to finish multiple articles within the same second? Does calling set() truncate the time and just leave me with the date?

Comment: *I appreciate this comment from both of you. I'm going to look at the python collections docs for multisets, you bring up a good point https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a *generator* for `article_read_date`, indeed:

```
article_read_date = (article_list.read_date for article_list in article_list)
```

This means that *after* you have iterated over it, the generator is "*exhausted*". Another loop over the iterator will not yield any values anymore. An illustrative example is the following:

```
>>> l = [1,4,2,5]
>>> g = (x for x in l)
>>> list(g)
[1, 4, 2, 5]
>>> list(g)
[]
```

as you can see, the second `list(g)` does not produces any values anymore.

You can create a set with:

```
article_read_date = [a.read_date for a in context['readArticleList']]

def count_since(iterable, _timed):
    timestamp = timezone.now() - timed
    return sum(x > timestamp for x in iterable)

context['articles_last30'] = count_since(article_read_date, timedelta(days=30))
context['articles_last60'] = count_since(article_read_date, timedelta(days=60))
context['articles_last90'] = count_since(article_read_date, timedelta(days=90))
```

That being said, since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), [**`Count`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id8) has a `filter=` attribute, so you can count the articles with one extra query like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

nw = timezone.now()

context.update(
    context['readArticleList'].aggregate(
        articles_last30=Count('pk', filter=Q(read_date__gt=nw-timedelta(days=30))),
        articles_last60=Count('pk', filter=Q(read_date__gt=nw-timedelta(days=60))),
        articles_last90=Count('pk', filter=Q(read_date__gt=nw-timedelta(days=90)))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful! So calling set(article_read_date ) or set(article_list.read_date for article_list in article_list) would have solved the issue as well? *I like your way more anyway, but just trying to further understand where I went wrong.

Comment: @Dssii3056: yes, if you would have constructed a `set(..)` then you can iterate over it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are doing in a much more efficient way and cleaner way.

First though you should Note that the convention is models are not named in plural. So it is not `Articles.objects..` but `Article.objects..`. You should rename your model to `Article` instead of `Articles`.

If we assume that as should be the case that `Article(s)` is a model which has field read date.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    read_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ... other_fields ..
```

Since you very much want efficiency. You can count the results straight from the DB.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
    thirty_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
    sixty_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(day=60)
    ninty_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(day=90)

    ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    ctx['articles_last90'] = \
     Article.objects.filter(read_date__gt=ninty_days_ago).count()
    ctx['articles_last60'] = \
    Article.objects.filter(read_date__gt=sixty_days_ago).count()
    ctx['last_last30'] = \
    Article.objects.filter(read_date__gt=thirty_days_ago).count()

    return ctx
```

This way you never ever load anything into python memory except the number of articles. It is much better than iterating or even using len(list_of_items).
You just have to be conscious of that `read_time__gt=ninty_days_ago` means articles that were last read more than ninty days ago.

See more from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: But this will result in three extra queries, whereas we can do that in a single query.

Comment: Those three queries are much more efficient than whatever else you are doing. Because they all run at the database level which is much efficient than running it as python objects in django. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but the last solution works at the database level as well, except that we make three `Count(..)`s on the same `JOIN`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that is okay, the previous solution is also good. It is good you mark it as the accepted answer. There are always different approaches to the same problem. I would prefer a more straight forward approach for new persons.